# Energy in a wave

Tags: ac, energy

The energy of a wave is defined as w=a^2.
w=energy
a=amplitude.

Does this formula also apply to AC or rectified AC?

When two waves with identical polarization, frequency, phase and amplitude propagate in the same direction and meet (and merge) is it appropriate to add together the amplitudes to calculate the amplitude of the resulting wave?

Answer (score 0):

We tend to talk about the *power* of a signal in EE and yes, that power (energy/time) is proportional to the amplitude squared. We refine this and talk about RMS and RMS is the square root of the mean of the square of the signal.

When two signals with identical frequency and phase meet we simply add them together like 3 + 2 = 5.

If the two signals are not so coherent then we add the amplitudes like this:

$$\sqrt{3^2+2^2} = 3.606$$

Comment: That being the case the energy of the resulting merged wave would be (2a)^2=4a^2. Therefore the energy of the merged wave has doubled that of the two individual waves.

Comment: In EE signal terms (remembering that this is an EE site), double amplitude means 4 times the energy.

Comment: That would violate conservation of energy. If we take two units of energy from the output and feed it back into the input, then there are still two units remaining for utilization and the process can go on continuously.

Comment: Yes but I'm talking about voltages that can deliver power to a load (this is an EE site) and you seem to be talking about something else. You asked: "Does this formula also apply to AC or rectified AC?"

Comment: There is an electromagnetic wave associated with AC.

Comment: Yes, in the far field there is one, at about 1 wavelength away and provided that the "radiator" is reasonably tuned to produce E and H fileds in the ratio of \$120\pi:1\$. This will produce a far-field. In the near field, the electric and magnetic fields can behave as I have stated. Take note that I beleive this converstation is going nowhere.